# How to remove a role from all users who have it with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot that removes a specific role from all users who has it on the server. I have tried this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def massremoverole(role: discord.Role):
    guild = bot.get_guild(int(746337818388987967))
    for member in guild.members:
        for role in role.members: 
            if member.has_role(role=True):
                await member.remove_roles
```

also it doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@bot.command()
async def massremoverole(role: discord.Role):
    guild = bot.get_guild(746337818388987967)
    for member in guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
                member.remove_roles(role)
```

I recomment you to do `guild = ctx.guild` instead of `guild = bot.get_guild(746337818388987967)` but it's up to you.

Comment: you dont need to iterate through member roles, you can just `if role in member.roles:`